# How to vertically align woocommerce prices?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem.
My webpage product catalog was set to equal height by CSS

```
.product-list-item.prod-layout-classic .kw-details, .woocommerce ul.products li.product .product-list-item.prod-layout-classic .kw-details {
    height: 200px !important;
}
```

And now, my prices are off the alignment, I know the problem is that some of the product title takes two lines, but I can't make my prices to be aligned vertically.

This is the website that I am trying to fix - [here](https://www.snackbox.lt/dovana-2/)

As you can see, the prices for products that has two line title are dropped down.

Tried all kinds of css code, but none seems to work.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, 1. You can use 'absolute' for your amount div and align it from bottom.. 2. you can set height your heading or use match height jquery to heading ..

Comment: Wow. Your idea of heading size worked.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding the following CSS rule to make heading size equal:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .product-list-item.prod-layout-classic .kw-details-title {
    height: 50px;
}
```